# unix shell scripting subtraction for floating point numbers

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/ksh

a=8.3
b=10.20
diff=`expr $b - $a`
echo "$diff"
```

its giving

> expr: 0402-046 A specified operator requires numeric parameters. error i want output as 1.9

Comment: you could use `bc` instead : `echo $b-$a | bc`. On the command line `expr 3.2 - 2` gives the same result. It seems that expr can't take float: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165165/arithmetic-operations-with-expr-and-variables

Comment: @Giri: You can provide feedback on the provided answer and accept it ( a small tick mark on left of the answer) to mark the post resolved.

Comment: As per the remarks added by a helpful person [to your later question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41165923/472495), we do expect you to interact with people who assist you. I have upvoted the post below, and downvoted your post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `bc` for this, use the native arithmetic operators in `ksh`

```
#!/bin/ksh

a=8.3
b=10.20
printf "%.2f\n" "$((b - a))"
```

outputs

```
$ ksh script.ksh
1.90
```