# File redirection inside for loop

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have am redirecting the file inside file but at the last the file is going to nullify, my code is like below

```
#!/bin/ksh
newlycreated=`cat /axphome/gdevarad/file.txt|awk '{print $1}'`

for i in $newlycreated
do

    cat file1.txt |grep -v $i > /axphome/gdevarad/file1.txt

done
```

`file.txt` contains

```
india    30
pakistan 40
```

`file1.txt` contains

```
india    30
pakistan 40
germany  50
japan    60
aus      70
```

Comment: You are not providing feedback on any of the answers to the question you are posting, the last one being http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059906/unix-shell-scripting-subtraction-for-floating-point-numbers, unless you appreciate what people are doing to help you, you won't get much response here!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `> /axphome/gdevarad/file1.txt` with `>> /axphome/gdevarad/file1.txt` so you do not overwrite your results in every loop.
Evn better: Place `> /axphome/gdevarad/file1.txt` after `done` .